# TypeError: this.datasource.getProducts is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

I am using the latest version of angular9  and am trying to write a unit test to test Service that gets a list of products.

When running ng test in visual code terminal it fails for the test: "**TypeError: this.datasource.getProducts is not a function**" with error :

[after doing **ng serve** I get an error in the console(click here to see image).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUKm3.png)

As shown in the above image, the product.repository.ts code given below.

**product.repository.ts**

```
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { StaticDataSource } from './static.datasource';

@Injectable()
export class ProductRepository {

  private products: Product[] = [];
  private categories: string[] = [];

  constructor(private datasource: StaticDataSource) {
      this.datasource.getProducts().subscribe( data =>
        {
          this.products = data;
          this.categories = data.map(p => p.category)
          // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
          .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
        });
  }

  getProducts(category: string = null): Product[]
  {
    return this.products
    .filter(p => category == null || category == p.category);
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Product
  {
    return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
  }

  getCategories(): string[] {
    return this.categories;
  }

}
```

Below is the code of static.datasource.ts

**static.datasource.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { Order } from './order.model';

@Injectable()
export class StaticDataSource {

  private products: Product[] = [
    new Product(1, 'Flyraom Lace up shoe', 'Category 1', 'Sneaker Shoe (Category 1)', 100),
    new Product(2, 'T-Shirt', 'Category 1', 'Sports T-shirt High Quality (Category 1)', 90),
    new Product(3, 'TR Trail Shoe', 'Category 1', 'Running Shoe (Category 1)', 99),
    new Product(4, 'Cooler', 'Category 1', 'High Quality Cooler (Category 1)', 50),
    new Product(5, 'Graphic T-Shirt Grey L', 'Category 1', 'Cotton T-shirt (Category 1)', 60),
    new Product(6, 'Euphoria EDP 100 ml', 'Category 2', 'Liquid Amber, Black Violet, Cream, Mahogany Wood (Category 2)', 150),
    new Product(7, 'Eternity Moment EDP 100 ml', 'Category 2', 'Brazillian Rose Wood, Cashmere Wood, Musk (Category 2)', 80),
    new Product(8, 'In Red EDT 100 ml', 'Category 2', 'Lily, Jasmine, Violet Leaf, Rose, Blackcurrant (Category 2)', 90),
    new Product(9, 'Flower Pink EDT 100 ml', 'Category 2', 'Othmani Roses', 99),
    new Product(10, 'Musk EDC 59 ml', 'Category 2', 'Musk EDC 59 ml', 88),
    new Product(11, 'Shampo', 'Category 3', 'Favourite Shampoo', 188),
    new Product(12, 'Biscuit', 'Category 4', 'Crunchy Biscuit', 88),
    new Product(13, 'Chips', 'Category 5', 'Salted & crunchy tasty Chips', 150)
  ];

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return from([this.products]);
  }

  saveOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order>
  {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(order));
    return from([order]);
  }
}
```

Comment: either declare your StaticDataSource  in a module or write `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` to declare it as global

Comment: I already declare in the module providers array

Comment: providers: [
     ProductRepository,
     StaticDataSource,
     Cart,
     Order,
     OrderRepository,
     { provide: StaticDataSource, useClass: RestDataSource },
     RestDataSource, AuthService
    ]

Comment: You listed StaticDataSource as a provider but you tell it to use the class RestDataSource, which is probably missing the getProducts() method.

Comment: So, how should I solve this problem? Please give me solution

Comment: `useClass` creates a new instance of service. What will happen when you use `useExisting` instead of it?

Comment: not working on this solution, the same error is coming

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above, you listed `StaticDataSource` as a provider but you're mapping the class name `StaticDataSource` to `RestDataSource`.

That means that when you inject the `StaticDataSource` service into your component you're actually calling the RestDataSource class.  My guess based on the information provided is that the `RestDataSource` class is probably missing a getProducts() method.

In your app.module.ts file change this:

`providers: [ ProductRepository, StaticDataSource, Cart, Order, OrderRepository, { provide: StaticDataSource, useClass: RestDataSource }, RestDataSource, AuthService ]`

to this:

`providers: [ ProductRepository, StaticDataSource, Cart, Order, OrderRepository, StaticDataSource, RestDataSource, AuthService ]`

Comment: When I remove this code { provide: StaticDataSource, useClass: RestDataSource } from the provider array I am failed to login to the admin panel.

Comment: That's unrelated to the above question.  Based on the code you posted, the answer above is correct.  I would assume that your login function stopped working for the same reason, that you're calling methods in classes that don't exist.  But without any code to look at it's impossible to say.